# Unable to see GMail Actions in email sent to self

Tags: gmail, schema.org

I'm trying to test a gmail "Go-To Action" in an email.  I followed the instructions to send the email over SMTP to myself, so that it's from and to the same address, but the action isn't showing up.  Google's email validator says the email is fine.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Return-Path: <workspace@example.com>
Received: from gmail.com (c-24-5-42-195.hsd1.ca.comcast.net. [24.5.42.195])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id zq5sm15392663pbb.37.2014.08.03.15.47.32
        for <workspace@example.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 03 Aug 2014 15:47:32 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <53debc04.c5a7440a.7465.5fae@mx.google.com>
X-Google-Original-Message-ID: ws-5.example.com
Return-Path: <no-reply@example.com>
Date: Sun, 03 Aug 2014 15:47:31 -0700
From: 'Admin' <workspace@example.com>
Reply-To: 'Admin' <workspace@example.com>
To: workspace@example.com
Subject: New message in testing
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_53debc035aaca_16dc93fed86033be07762b";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-Example-Post: 5


----==_mimepart_53debc035aaca_16dc93fed86033be07762b
Date: Sun, 03 Aug 2014 15:47:31 -0700
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <53debc037b851_16dc93fed86033be077729@Andrews-MacBook-Air.local.mail>

THIS IS THE TEXT VERSION, skipped for this example.


----==_mimepart_53debc035aaca_16dc93fed86033be07762b
Date: Sun, 03 Aug 2014 15:47:31 -0700
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <53debc037f5be_16dc93fed86033be0778f3@Andrews-MacBook-Air.local.mail>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            color: #333;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        h2, h3, h4 {
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        a {
            color: #5572BC;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        p {
          margin-bottom: 18px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: white;">
      <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
          "@context":              "http://schema.org",
          "@type":                 "EmailMessage",
          "description":           "View your Project",
          "action": {
            "@type":               "ViewAction",
            "url":                 "http://example.com/",
            "name":                "View Project"
          },
          "publisher": {
            "@type":               "Organization",
            "name":                "Example",
            "url":                 "https://example.com"
          }
        }
      </script>

  <div style='margin-left: 10px;'>
    <div style='font-weight: bold;'>
      New message in your Example.com Project
    </div>

    <p>Again again?</p>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_53debc035aaca_16dc93fed86033be07762b--
```

Comment: How can I get someone to help me with this?